# How avoid dependencies when using Xerces?

Tags: c++, dependencies, xerces

I'm trying to integrate xerces 3.1.1 with my program, but it requires libcurl for linux and libicui18n, libicuuc, libicudata, libm for Mac OS X and Solaris. Are there some flags which can be passed to `configure` to avoid all this dependencies?

Comment: Why not use a XML library that doesn't have any? TinyXML or something?

Comment: @Pubby If you will ask question about QT I wound't suggest to use MFC. Your question is from other Opera :) The reason is that TinyXML, RapidXML and other popular and small libraries have no xml validation. They are only parsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following `configure` options when building:

```
--disable-netaccessor-curl
```

to get rid of cURL, and

```
--disable-transcoder-icu
```

to get rid of ICU. You can't get rid of a `libm` dependency, nor should you want to. `libm` implements part of the C++ language standard.

Check the output from `./configure --help` to see other potential dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
 
`./configure --without-icu`
you can use the `--without` option to disable any package